# Downloading stock information from Yahoo! Finance

Tags: vba, excel, finance, web-scraping

The program downloads stock information from Yahoo! Finance and displays it in the spreadsheet.  On my Mac the program takes 10 minutes to get data for approximately 4000 stocks and on the PC it takes 45 minutes.  I wrote another version which copies and pastes the data instead of iterating through each price value, but every time I run that macro, the runtime increases.  That version takes about 15 minutes on a PC and 45 minutes on a Mac.

I don't know what is going on but I just want a program that runs in < 15 minutes on both operating systems and has a consistent runtime.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim numb_tickers As Integer
numb_tickers =        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, 2), Sheet1.Cells(5000, 2)))
numb_tickers = 5000 - numb_tickers

Dim start_ticker As Integer
start_ticker = Sheet3.Cells(5, 2) + 1
Dim end_ticker As Integer
end_ticker = Sheet3.Cells(6, 2) + 1

Dim x As Integer
For x = start_ticker To end_ticker

    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim qurl As String
    Dim nQuery As Name
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Sheets("Data").Cells.Clear

    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet

        StartDate = Sheet3.Cells(2, 2)
        EndDate = Sheet3.Cells(3, 2)
        Symbol = Sheet1.Cells(x, 2)
        Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

        qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol
        qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
            "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
            Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=" & Sheets("Data").Range("a1") & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & _
            Symbol & "&x=.csv"

QueryQuote:
             With Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"))
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
                On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .SaveData = True
            End With

            Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

         Sheets("Data").Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12


Dim numb_days As Integer
numb_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Data").Range(Sheet2.Cells(2, 7), Sheet2.Cells(1000, 7)))
numb_days = 1000 - numb_days

Dim z As Integer
For z = 2 To numb_days + 1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, z + 5) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(z, 7)

Next z

ErrorHandler:  Resume Next

Next x

Dim xyz As Integer
For xyz = 2 To numb_days + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, xyz + 5) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(xyz, 1)
Next xyz

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible the mac just has better specs?

Comment: I'm with John, check the specs. My macbook has a quad core processor and three times the memory of my Windows desktop.

Comment: Specs are not the issue.  The PC I am using is much more powerful than my macbook.

Comment: I'm thinking it could be some difference between excel 2007 and mac excel 2011

Comment: Seems more likely to be related to the speed of the machine's network connection than anything else...  Instead of using a querytable you might try using `Workbooks.Open()` and passing in the URL as the filename.

Comment: Use a swarm. [See this related answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74656/41243)

Comment: Yahoo finance API is not available anymore. I have moved to MarketXLS after this change, much more reliable data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the sound of using a swarm as suggested by @Rubberduck but I doubt that VbScript will run on a Mac. I thought I would make some general suggestions about your VBA code.

1. When adding a `QueryTable` using VBA you should be aware that Excel creates both a data connection and a named range. If you are running a process that has a large number of loops this can result in lots of connections and named ranges. I suggest you delete them after you have got the data.

   ```
   Dim tempQueryTable As QueryTable

   qurl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" & Symbol
   qurl = qurl & "&a=" & Month(StartDate) - 1 & "&b=" & Day(StartDate) & _
       "&c=" & Year(StartDate) & "&d=" & Month(EndDate) - 1 & "&e=" & _
       Day(EndDate) & "&f=" & Year(EndDate) & "&g=" & Sheets("Data").Range("a1") & "&q=q&y=0&z=" & _
       Symbol & "&x=.csv"

   Set tempQueryTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, _
       Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a1"))

    With tempQueryTable
       .BackgroundQuery = True
       .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
       .SaveData = True
   End With

   ' do something with the data here
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns _
       Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
       Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12

   ' delete the named range that gets created
   ThisWorkbook.Names(tempQueryTable.Name).Delete
   ' delete the query table
   tempQueryTable.Delete

   ' ... other code here
   ```
2. Avoid looping over blocks of cells in Excel whenever possible. Perform a single operation on the whole range. So the loops where you write the Adj Close prices and the dates becomes:

   ```
   ' Copy the Adj Close prices
   'Dim z As Integer
   '        For z = 2 To numb_days + 1
   '            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:=z + 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(RowIndex:=z, ColumnIndex:=7)
   '        Next z
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowIndex:=x, ColumnIndex:=7).Resize(ColumnSize:=numb_days).Value = _
       Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(RowIndex:=2, ColumnIndex:=7).Resize(RowSize:=numb_days).Value)

   ' Other code here ...

   ' Copy the dates
   'Dim xyz As Integer
   '    For xyz = 2 To numb_days + 1
   '        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, xyz + 5) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(xyz, 1)
   '    Next xyz
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowIndex:=1, ColumnIndex:=7).Resize(ColumnSize:=numb_days).Value = _
       Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(RowIndex:=2, ColumnIndex:=1).Resize(RowSize:=numb_days).Value)
   ```
3. I have found that calling Application.WorksheetFunction can be quite slow. You can use the `Rows.Count` property to find out how much data you have. So the code to count the number of days can become:

   ```
   'numb_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheets("Data").Range(Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 7), Worksheets("Data").Cells(1000, 7)))
   'numb_days = 1000 - numb_days
   numb_days = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2 ' first row is headers, last row is empty
   ```
4. You define a `Worksheet` variable but then never actually use it. Using such variables can make your code much easier to read.

   ```
   Dim DataSheet As Worksheet

   ' define this once outside the loop
   Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

   For x = start_ticker To end_ticker
       ' Lines such as this one become much easier to read
       'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells.Clear
       DataSheet.Cells.Clear
   ```
5. You can use the `Timer` function to work out the number of seconds a certian chunk of code takes. This helps you focus on the worst performing code without having to guess what is taking the longest to run. However, getting data from the internet is something that you have little control over.

Comment: Hey man thank you so much.  You are a life saver.  Deleting the contents of the query table fixed everything.  I've received roughly 30 comments over the last two days regarding this code and you were the only one who was able to find the key problem with the code.  You have some good knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what would cause the large difference in time, but I found a couple minor factors:

- `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is performed in each loop (~4 000 times I assume)
- `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is not only performed in the same volume but also **not negated** in the scope of this question.
- The lack of `.Value2` has a potential performance demerit as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2).